# Deny docker container to write host's filesystem

Tags: docker, apparmor

I have 2 computers, one is using fedora. When I use this command on fedora :

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/test:/host/tmp/test ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I'm not able to write/read files from my host. **This is the behavior I want**.

The problem is : with ubuntu when I use the same command. The container can read/write every files on host. I don't want this.

I think on Fedora SELINUX is protecting my system. How can I do it with AppArmor?

I did many research on the Internet but I only found topics about how to allow the write on host's filesystem ... /:

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

**EDIT**

Computers are free access so I cannot control how the user will execute docker run. I need a protection from host and apparmor daemon.

Comment: Do you have an AppArmor profile that will deny writing to file system?  If so you can use [this:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/)  `docker run --rm -it --security-opt apparmor=your_profile hello-world`

Comment: As an aside, this [project](https://github.com/jessfraz/bane) might be of use to you.  Specifically [this](https://github.com/jessfraz/bane/blob/master/docker-nginx-sample) apparmor profile for denying file access & specific command tools

Comment: I forgot to write it. But these computers are open acess so I cannot control how the user will execute docker run

Comment: Are you able to just edit the [default apparmor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/#understand-the-policies) with a more restrictive apparmor profile?  Does this work for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to mark the bind mount as read-only:

```
docker run -ti -v /tmp/test:/host/tmp/test:ro ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: This also has the advantage of being portable to other Docker environments (where selinux/apparmor may not be available on a given setup).

Comment: or... Don't run container processes as root and control access on the host via traditional methods.   Relying on the container to behave properly with root access is troublesome.

Comment: A read-only bind mount isn't a feature of the container, it's a feature of the kernel. That being said, for a truly secure system, you would do all three: 1. mount it read-only, 2. run the container as non-root and deny access via file permissions, *and* 3. use SELinux/AppArmor to prevent unauthorized actions.

Comment: You cannot run container without root privilege... Even if you use docker group. I tried to use docker group and i'm still able to read/write protected file.

Comment: @VenderAeloth The `docker` group lets you run Docker commands as non-root users. To run the Docker process itself as a non-root user, you can pass the `--user` option to `docker run`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/user

Comment: To clarify, the "Docker container* process itself" (i.e. not dockerd or containerd).